# Can a Rails Model have an array of associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I've looked everywhere, and can't find anything (maybe cause it's not possible)

I have a Meeting model and a Language model (which has a string column called language). Each Meeting has 2 Languages.

Is there a way to make an association, such as:
rails g migration AddLanguageToMeetings language:references

And then store an array of 2 language_ids in the reference?

For example, `Meeting.language_id = [1,2]`

And then be able to call the Language, like:

`meeting.language_id[0].language`

How can I se up this association? Do I need to have 2 different columns with each associated id?

Thanks!!

Comment: NO. you can't have associaions via array of ids .. couple of ways to do it: `has_many :through, belongs_to :through` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` depending on your use case.. [read here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a `has_many`, where the foreign key exists in the `languages` table, or in a joining table between the `languages` and `meetings` tables.

If you want each `Meeting` to point two exactly two `Language`s, then you can use two foreign keys in the `meetings` table, give each language a real name, and then have two `belongs_to` associations in your `Meeting`.

Comment: bummer. I feel like it's repetitive to create 2 columns, but if that's the only way... Thanks!

Comment: Again, no, `has_many` is also a completely valid way to do this.

Comment: You can use a validation to enforce a maximum number of associations.

Comment: This is a bad design. What if you will have more, that 2 languages? What if you will have to implement comments or other additional data to each language, participating in meeting? Use join table, as @jan-minárik described.

Comment: @AntonAL Read my answer again, that's my first suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

What you want is a N-to-N relation. Create another model called MeetingLanguage with two columns:

```
create_table :meeting_languages do |t|
    t.references :meetings
    t.references :languages
end
```

and associations:

```
class MeetingLanugage < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :language
    belongs_to :meeting
end
```

And then in Meeting module:

```
has_many :meeting_languages
has_many :languages, through: :meeting_languages, source: :language
```

Now you can have as many languages as you want for a single meeting.